# Display multiple links in one popup window

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

In my application I have multiple links, each link is opened in popup window.

My idea is to open only one popup (the first link may be displayed by default), 
and the others may be selected and displayed directly in this popup window. .

I'm trying to found the different possibilities to approach this result.

An Example of code I have:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Show Content</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
 <a href="www.google.com" onclick="openpopup(this.href,window1);return false;">link1</a>
 <a href="www.google.com" onclick="openpopup(this.href,window1);return false;">link2</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctr=0;
function openpopup(popurl,winName){
//var winName = "win_"+(ctr++);
winpops=window.open(popurl,winName,"width=300,height=382,scrollbars=no")
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just adding the winpops variable in your other popups.
your winpopups instanciate the window and gives parent/child link so if you add something like :

```
 onclick="openpopup(this.href,'window1')"
```

and in your JS :

```
function openpopup(popupurl, winName) {
 winpops = window.open(...,winName,...)
}
```

that should work. I didn't test it :)

Comment: I Tried and doesn't work: no popup opened.
I edited my code with your suggestions

Comment: That works well as seen here (well jsfiddle blocks popups but I tried it locally) : http://jsfiddle.net/cquQ8/   By the way add 'window1' instead of window1 AND most important put your <script> tags IN body and not outside, as your code does currently.

Comment: Ok, I understand your proposition. It better that I had.
is there a solution to add links directly in the popup?
I know I need to implement a code more complexe for that.